# Interactive dashboard to show plot using shiny in R

Tags: r, plot, shiny, dashboard, rcharts

This is first my attempt in shiny. I am creating a dashboard that would take 'date range' and 'variable name' as input from user and show the plot. dates along x axis and values along y axis. I am using rCharts library to make plot.

Sample dataset in csv file:

```
Date        Total_Orders   Delivered_orders   Cancelled_orders   NEW_USERS_COUNT 
2015-04-30     23             12               2                  21
2015-05-01     43             21               12                 32
2015-05-02     32             13               10                 30
2015-05-03     43             32               7                  14
2015-05-04     43             22               3                  21
2015-05-05     32             21               1                  22
```

I wrote ui.R and script.R as below. But It shows ui but not the plot in mainbody.

My code:

ui.R

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')

dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),

  dashboardSidebar(
               dateRangeInput("daterange", "Select Date range:",
                              start = "2001-01-01",
                              end = "2010-12-31"),
               selectInput("var", "Choose a variable to display",
                           choices = c('Total_Orders' = 'Total_Orders', 
                                       'Delivered_orders' = 'Delivered_orders', 
                                       'Cancelled_orders' = 'Cancelled_orders', 
                                       'NEW_USERS_COUNT' = 'NEW_USERS_COUNT'),
                           selected = "Total_Orders")

               ),
  dashboardBody(
    showOutput("chart1", "polycharts"),

    )
  )
```

server.R

```
library("shiny")
library("rCharts")
options(RCHART_WIDTH = 800)

file <-  read.csv('file path.csv',  header = TRUE)

shinyServer(function(input, output)

  {output$chart1 <- renderChart({

               date <- input$daterange

               data <- switch(input$var,
               'Total_Orders' = file$Total_Orders, 
               'Delivered_orders' = file$Delivered_orders, 
               'Cancelled_orders' = file$Cancelled_orders, 
               'NEW_USERS_COUNT' = file$NEW_USERS_COUNT)


  rPlot(x = list(var = "date"), y = "data", 
             data = file, type = 'bar')
  })
 })
```

Is there a better way to show the plot in the dashboard?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work 100%, but here are a few things you should check: 1. The output chart in the `dashboardBody` should be inside a `fluidRow`, inside a `box`. 2. You're supposed to give column names to `rPlot` `x` and `y`, not the data itself, since you're telling the function to take the data from `file`. 3. For some reason, your data doesn't appear when using `type="bar"`. Try `type="line"` instead, at least for now.

Comment: @Molx I included box and fluidRow, though it is showing the box but not the plot. `dashboardBody(
   
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "plot", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
          collapsible = TRUE, plotOutput("chart1", height = 250, width = 500)) 
      )`

Comment: server.R = `shinyServer(function(input, output)
  
  {output$chart1 <- renderChart({
            
                   date <- input$daterange  point <- switch(input$var,
                   'Total_Orders' = file$Total_Orders, 
                   'Delivered_orders' = file$Delivered_orders, 
                   'Cancelled_orders' = file$Cancelled_orders, 
                   'NEW_USERS_COUNT' = file$NEW_USERS_COUNT) ggplot(file, aes(date, point)) + geom_line() }) }) `                   **I tried ggplot this time**

Comment: this is the error I am getting: `Error in paste(c(cht_style, rChart_$html()), collapse = "\n") : 
  attempt to apply non-function`

Comment: @Molx I made few changes in the code and the plot is shown now but the plot doesn't change as I change the dates. `shinyServer(function(input, output) {output$chart1 <- renderPlot({start_date <- input$daterange[1] end_date <- input$daterange[2] subset(file, date >= start_date & date   <= start_date)  point <- switch(input$var,  'Total_Orders' = file$Total_Orders,   'Delivered_orders' = file$Delivered_ordes,  'NEW_USERS_COUNT' = file$NEW_USERS_COUNT) plot(file$date, point)}) })` . Can you suggest some inputs so that the plot changes as I change the date range in the app.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way to change the plot according to the date is updating the `x` `axis` limits instead of selecting a different data subset. By the way you should update your question with the recent code changes  so someone can give an answer, now that some issues have been fixed.